# Solution of Matrix differential equation $\textbf{X}'(t)=\textbf{A}\textbf{X}(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

As I know the solution of the equation system is $\textbf{X}=e^{At}\textbf{X}(0)$.

I want to symbolize fundamental set of solution of matrix dif. equation $\textbf{X}'=\textbf{AX}$ where $\textbf{X}_{4x1}$ and $A_{4x4}$ are matrices. So , I need linearly independent solutions of the Dif. Equation.

(If I have specified Matrix $A$, I can easily find the linearly independent solutions by finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors $A$,  but now I can' t write since I don' t know $A$. )

I just know that $A$ has four distinct complex eigenvalues $\lambda_1=a i$,
 $\lambda_2=-a i$,
  $\lambda_3=b i$,  $\lambda_4=-b i$.

Comment: Erm... What is your question? Haven't you "symbolized" the solution by writing $X = e^{tA}X(0)$ already?

Comment: Yes, But  I need to symbolize linearly independent solutions of the Matrix Dif. Equation in order to write the fundamental set of solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since we $A$ has 4 disctinct eigenvalues, we can write $UDU^{-1}=A$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing $ai, -ai, bi, -bi$ and $U$ is a matrix containing the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$. Then we have

$$\exp(At)X(0)=\exp(UDU^{-1})X(0)=U \begin{pmatrix}e^{ait} & & &\\&e^{-ait}&&\\ &&e^{bit}&\\&&&e^{-bit}\end{pmatrix}U^{-1}X(0).$$

Is this closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you Roland. What is fundamental Matrix in this question?

Comment: If you have a basis of four vectors, you can replace X(0) by each of them to obtain a fundamental system of solutions. For example, if $X_j$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_j$ ($j=1,2,3,4$), a possible fundamental system is $\{e^{\lambda_1t}X_1,\ldots,e^{\lambda_4t}X_4\}$.